# Android how to print barcode from esc printer

Tags: java, android, printing, thermal-printer

i manage to print out barcode from my android apps to ip thermal printer. but in my case i only can print out the text from my printer , the barcode image can't work. Any suggestion to print out the barcode from ESC thermal printer.

```
  public void print_bar_code(String content) {

    byte[] formats = {(byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0x49};
    byte[] contents = content.getBytes();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[formats.length + contents.length + 1];

    System.arraycopy(formats, 0, bytes, 0, formats.length);
    System.arraycopy(contents, 0, bytes, formats.length, contents.length);

    try {
        writer.write(String.valueOf(formats));
        writer.write(String.valueOf(contents));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```